# Is it dangerous to be around old paint?

Tags: paint, shed, old-house

We live in a house that is around 60 years old. For the record, we live in Northern California, near San Francisco. About a year ago, when searching through our shed, we accidentally spilled a paint can all over the floor. The shed is open to the elements and it has heavily rained multiple times, possibly washing the paint away. We are considering reentering the area, but are concerned whether there is poisonous material in the paint, and we haven't entered the area. It is safe to go in the area?

Comment: The danger from old paint is the possibility of it containing lead.  Lead is dangerous if eaten.  I would not eat the dirt/any wood.

Answer (score 6):

Unless the paint was adulterated with nuclear material, there is no real concern.

The house might be 60 years old, but the paint almost certainly wasn't, but even if it was that old and contained lead (you can buy test kits if you are that concerned), the paint is only a hazard if eaten or sanded into a powder and inhaled. Even then, one time exposure is unlikely to have any measurable effect.

If you do get a test and it does contain lead, you can simply paint over it with modern paints to mitigate the issue.

Comment: Would it be safe to take children (~10 years of age) into the shed to help with home improvement?

Comment: @Astrovis this question belongs at the top of this page in your post ... it does not belong in a comment  ... this site is not a chat forum

Comment: @Astrovis I don't see a concern, but you seem very concerned. Order a test kit online or go to probably any hardware store and get a lead test kit. They are quick and simple and will help to ease your concerns (unless the paint contains lead). Paint in the USA has not had lead in it since 1978.

Comment: Your shed is NOT Chernobyl.  The likelihood of anything being hazardous will come from other sources than paint spilled a year ago.  Use common sense and wear gloves and eye protection if you are cleaning things.  If there is dust from anything wear a mask.  Unless you plan on grinding the floor in an enclosed shed with no protection at all you should be safe...unless the shed is over a toxic waste dump.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you spilled it a year ago, so it's been dry for 11 months and some weeks.

Making it pretty much the same as the dry paint inside the house you presumably live in, though the dry paint inside the house is *far more likely to contain lead* being 60 years old, making it somewhat *more* hazardous, (at least to small children that eat paint chips) potentially.

I rather doubt a can of paint that was still able to spill was 60 years old (they usually rust through and dry in the can by that age.) So a spillable can in the shed (circa 2023) is not likely to contain lead. In any case, don't eat the paint.